# MDIContainer Grey Background (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, mdi

My application has a main form which is the parent of ALL MDIChild forms. It has its own cool little background.

[image]

I want to have 4 buttons on the Main Form that load a different form in the MDI Container.  My form is transparent so all the little designs ive made for my picture box buttons overlap the main form nicely UNTIL Visual Studio paints that stupid background grey when you set the IsMDIContainer property to true.  The buttons now have greyspots (as they are transparent and its like it bleeds through the background image and into the greyspot of the MDI Container).

I've googled this for hours and no one has answer.  I want the buttons to be transparent  to the Main Forms BG Image and NOT the grey MDIContainer BG.

Using VS2019,  VB.NET  The image above shows Form1 with the background and an overlayed Form 5 with all the controls.  I wanted the 2 cloud looking buttons at the bottom (which are supposed to be on the Parent Form 1) to not have that grey box around them but to be transparent to the Form1 background image.

Comment: Both MDI and transparency work in very specific ways in Windows Forms and, not surprisingly, you appear not to understand either at this stage. Please add a screenshot of your form, both in the designer and at run time, so we know what we're working with. What you want may not be possible and some sort of workaround may be required.

Comment: The MDI Form *grey background* is actually a Control, its class name is `MdiClient`.

Comment: Is the area on the left with your buttons not meant to change?  ...meaning only the area on the right would change with the different MdiChildren?  Instead of using the MDI setup, you could make the area where you want the "children" just a normal panel.  Then you create your children  forms and set [TopLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel?view=netcore-3.1) to false on them, allowing you to add them to the panel.  The area on the left would just be another panel.  You could set the background images however you like then...

Answer (score 0):

First,  you could use this code under your mdi parent load event:

```
For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MdiClient Then
        ctl.BackColor = Me.BackColor
    End If
Next ctl
```

but it will work only if you set a plain color (e.g. only red or orange or any other color) as backcolor to this mdi parent form, but doesn't work with images.

you must know that mdi parent forms are designed to show only the child forms, so if you want a background image for your form just use a regular form then add a panel or multiple panels to it instead of your mdi child forms which will do the same job plus enabling controls transparency.

for your information, mdi child forms is a very old technique which is rarely used today.